# Finding highest and lowest values from calculated xor operation with given (min, max) and scalar

Tags: algorithm, sorting

The purpose is to find the highest and lowerst xored values given (min, max) and scalar.

For example, the output should be 63 (13 ^ 50) with a given min (10), max(20), and 50 if we want to find the highest value.

It's simply done by iteration from the given min value to the max value, but it takes O(n). So, I'd like to get advice if I can get the same output with closer O(1).

Thank you.

Comment: If you are given an *arbitrary* array you *have to scan*: any `item` of the array can be a solution so you can't skip, `O(n)` time complexity is inevitable. if you are given consequent numbers (not an array), `10..20` (or just min and max - `10` and `20`) there's different problem and can be solved in `O(1)` time

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the question. I omitted an important piece of information, which is that array input is a linearly monotonic set. So, [0,1,2,3,4] is legal input, but not [0,1,3,4]. In this case, can I get achieve the same output with closer O(1)?

Comment: Is [0,3,6,9] legal input?

Comment: No. [0,3,6,9] is not legal input. [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] is legal input.

Comment: So can the array always be specified by just two numbers, like 0 and 9 in that case? Then why is it an array?

Comment: Exactly. Represented between (min, max). Sorry for the confusion. Let me fix the question. I'm so sorry for the confusion again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in time linear in the number of bits in the input. Start from the highest bit position downwards. For each bit, see if you can make that bit 1 in the output (ie: if there's a number in the range with a bit that's opposite to the "value" you've been given that's compatible with all the bits so far). If you can good, if you can't, then choose the alternative.